# Should view logic go in a UIView or (when applicable) its UIViewController?

Tags: cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, ios

I recently discovered that `UIView`s should only have `UIViewController`s when they fill the entire window (or are managed by another `UIViewController` such as a `UINavigationController` or `UISplitViewController`).  This quotation is from the documentation for [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You should not use view controllers to manage views that fill only a part of their window—that is, only part of the area defined by the application content rectangle. If you want to have an interface composed of several smaller views, embed them all in a single root view and manage that view with your view controller.

I usually put my view logic in the UIView even when it is managed by a UIViewController, yet I often find myself needing to access properties of the UIViewController such as its navigationController property.  However, UIViews are not supposed to be aware of their UIViewController.

My conclusion is that view logic should go in a UIView's UIViewController when one exists, and in the UIView itself otherwise.

Alternatively, is it better practice to create a controller class for a view which is *not* a subclass of UIViewController?  UIPopoverController (an NSObject subclass) appears to follow this pattern, although in most cases (UIButton, etc.) views do not seem to have dedicated controller classes.

Comment: Also, should UIViewControllers ever be used without a nib/xib file (i.e., a UIView which is created in code)?

Comment: Personally, I rarely use NIB files, so yes, you can absolutely use UIViewController and pals without them.

Comment: The fact that -initWithNibName:bundle: is UIViewController's designated initializer seems to indicate that it is not intended to be used without a nib.

Comment: And the parameter names for `initWithNibName:bundle:` are `nibNameOrNil` and `bundleOrNil`, which would indicate that it's intended to be used either way.

Comment: @Alex: Interesting tidbit, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application logic should never go in a `UIView`. Period. The purpose of a `UIViewController` is to manage a view and its subviews and, under most circumstances, is the appropriate place for the logic. UIKit adheres to the Model-View-Controller paradigm. Models hold the data, views display it and accept input, and controllers manage the interaction between the other two layers. That's why the controller is the logical place for application logic. In iOS, `UIViewController` and its subclasses are the usual controller classes. I'd suggest [reading up on Apple's guidance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) to better understand this pattern and how it's used in iOS.

The quote from Apple's documentation is telling you that you don't create a `UIViewController` for each label or button. You create one for each "page" or "screen" of your application and you use it to manage the controls in that view. Notice that UIKit has classes to manage table views, tab views and navigation views. That's the level of object that you would use `UIViewController` to manage.

I'd recommend browsing through the iOS examples included with the SDK. They should give you a good idea of how the framework expects applications to be structured.

Comment: What about a UISwitch (or any other control)?  It is a UIView subclass which manages its own state.

Comment: Managing its own state isn't what I mean by logic. I mean application logic, like deciding to show a dialog to the user or saving a file. A `UISwitch` should know whether it's on or off, but it shouldn't be responsible for saving its value to the user's preferences file, for example. That's the job of a view controller.

Answer (score 3):

I came from the Win32 + .NET + Java Swing GUI world and I used to do the same thing.  But then I fixed my evil ways.  Now the only time I put code in UIView is if I wish to customize the VIEW ITSELF (OpenGL drawing, for example).

**Controllers set the state of the view.  The view renders its state.**